# Ruby Koans Quest 203(about_classes)- failed with rake

Tags: ruby

I encounter the issue when I filled the expected output and call rake. Is this something wrong with my setup or code?

> josephs-MacBook-Air:koans jj$ rake
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>   path_to_enlightenment.rb
>   AboutClasses#test_inside_a_method_self_refers_to_the_containing_object
>   has damaged your karma.
>
> The Master says:   You have not yet reached enlightenment.   I sense
>   frustration. Do not be afraid to ask for help.
>
> The answers you seek...   Expected "FILL ME IN" to equal
>
> Please meditate on the following code:
>   /Users/jj/Downloads/koans/about_classes.rb:162:in
>   `test_inside_a_method_self_refers_to_the_containing_object'
>
> remember that silence is sometimes the best answer your path thus far
>   [...................................X______________] 203/282

The code in question is:

```
class Dog7
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(initial_name)
      @name = initial_name
    end

    def get_self
      self
    end

    def to_s
      @name
    end

    def inspect
      "<Dog named '#{name}'>"
    end
  end

  def test_inside_a_method_self_refers_to_the_containing_object
    fido = Dog7.new("Fido")

    fidos_self = fido.get_self
    assert_equal __, fidos_self
  end
```

I put filled the assest_equal to

```
def test_inside_a_method_self_refers_to_the_containing_object
        fido = Dog7.new("Fido")

        fidos_self = fido.get_self
        assert_equal <Dog named 'Fido'>, fidos_self
      end
```

It explode.

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require': /Users/jtacuyan/Downloads/koans/about_classes.rb:162:
>   syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or
>   '(' (SyntaxError)
>       assert_equal <Dog named 'Fido'>, fidos_self
>                              ^ /Users/jj/Downloads/koans/about_classes.rb:162: syntax error,
>   unexpected ','
>       assert_equal <Dog named 'Fido'>, fidos_self
>                                       ^     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`
>   require'     from path_to_enlightenment.rb:28:in `<main>' rake aborted!
>   Command failed with status (1):
>   [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
>   /Users/jj/Downloads/koans/Rakefile:10:in`block in '
>   Tasks: TOP => default => test (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

I can execute it fine on irb though.

```
irb(main):016:0> fido = Dog7.new("Fido")
=> <Dog named 'Fido'>
irb(main):017:0> fido
=> <Dog named 'Fido'>
irb(main):018:0> fido.name
=> "Fido"
irb(main):019:0> fido.get_self
=> <Dog named 'Fido'>
irb(main):020:0> fidos_self = fido.get_self
=> <Dog named 'Fido'>
irb(main):021:0> fidos_self
=> <Dog named 'Fido'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the " in your assertion code.

```
assert_equal "<Dog named 'Fido'>", fidos_self
```

**UPDATED**

You should assert that `fidos_self` refers to itself, namely the instantiated `Dog7`: `fido`.

```
assert_equal fido, fidos_self
```

This is exactly what this test is supposed to do.

Comment: I've tried that as well, with no success.

 `The answers you seek...
  Expected "<Dog named 'Fido'>" to equal <Dog named 'Fido'>

Please meditate on the following code:
  /Users/jj/Downloads/koans/about_classes.rb:162:in `test_inside_a_method_self_refers_to_the_containing_object'

Answer (score 0):

The error is a type object error; the first element is a string type and the second is a Dog7 type. The solution is to match the types appropriately.

Check the return values of:

```
fidos_self.is_a?(String)
fidos_self.is_a?(Dog7)
fidos.is_a?(Dog7)
fidos_self
fidos
```